# Confusing myself with probability

Tags: probability, statistics

> A plane uses $1$ hour from $A$ to $B$. It has $2$ motors. Both motors works with a probability of $0.995$. If one motor (or both) fails, the plane crashes. How big is the probability the plane can get from $A$ to $B$?
>
> The answer is $0.990$.

I don't get why. $0.995\cdot 0.995$ is $0.990$, because $0.995\cdot 0.995$ should only work if they independent. I just don't see how they are independent, because if one motor fails, everything fails.

On the other hand, if I write $P($Motor1 flyes$|$Motor2 flyes$)$, I can kind of tell myself that Motor1 is independent, because if Motor1 flyes, the probability is equal to $0.995$ again meaning they are not dependent.

Any explanation is appreciated.

I have another question as well.

Check if $A$ and $B$ are independent, check if $A$ and $C$ are independent, and then check if $B$ and $C$ are independent without doing any calculations.

- $P(A)=0.90$
- $P(B)=0.85$
- $P(C)=0.81$
- $P(A \text{ and } B) = 0.765$
- $P(A \text{ and }C) = 0.77$
- $P(B \text{ and }C) = 0.73$
- $P(A \text{ and }B \text{ and }C) = 0.70$

I can manage to do it with a simple formula.

I used this formula:
$P(A|B)=P(A$ and $B)/P(B)$

I just don't understand how I can see the last one without calculations.

Comment: Your questions should really be submitted separately. ¶ Your concerns with the first question are appropriate.  Without the assumption of independence, the actual probability could be anywhere between $0.995$ and $0.995^2 \doteq 0.99$. ¶ On the second, you're not allowed to do *any* calculations?  There must be some proviso on that...

Comment: It may be the independence of both motors working is taken as granted as in many cases of real life it usually is the case.

Comment: Hi, Brian. I thought about separating them but I decided not to because it would just clutter things and I guess for most people here, they are both super simple questions. I can do calculations, but just not for the B and C part. Check the two first ones with calculations, and then B and C without.

Comment: @DavidLund I'll add my comment here in relation to the 2nd part of the question. If B depends on A, and A depends on C, then B must depend on C without the need for calculation.  The other way they may expect you to do it, is on the basis that you know $P(B)<1$ and therefore $P(A \lvert B)$ must be greater than $P(A$ and $B)$.  These are two ways it might be do-able without calculation.

Comment: @RobertFrost "If B depends on A, and A depends on C, then B must depend on C" No. "without the need for calculation" Sometimes "calculation" helps to see that a given assertion is absurd.

Comment: @RobertFrost in response to your comment about if $Pr(B)<1$ (*and $Pr(B)>0$*) then $Pr(A\mid B)$ being greater than $Pr(A\cap B)$, that is true regardless of whether $A$ and $B$ are independent directly from the definition of conditional probability since $Pr(B)\cdot Pr(A\mid B) = Pr(A\cap B)$ in every case regardless of the independence or dependence of the events.

Comment: @DavidLund my answer's now correct.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part .. 
Without the assumption of independence you can't conclude anything rigorously. For the second question.
$P(A|B)$ should be equal to $P(A)$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent..
So $0.90=0.765/0.85$ is that possible?
Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, yes you are right. A and B are independent, but that was just the formula I used :P A and C are not, and B and C are not. I am just wondering how you can see that B and C are not, without calculation (But calculating the others). Thanks.